# proof by induction in worded example

Tags: induction

I'm trying to answer the following question:

> The boxes Banana Ltd. uses to ship bananas come in two sizes, one that
>   holds three bananas and one that holds five bananas. The company promises to ship
>   at least as many bananas as you order. Show using induction that the company can
>   fulfil any order for nine or more bananas exactly.

The only thing I've been able to come up with is an equation:
$3x + 5y = n$ where $n$ refers to the number of bananas ordered.

Also for the cases where the number of bananas ordered is less than $9$, it is obvious that the company will be able to ship at least as many bananas as ordered.

I am unsure on how to proceed from here.

EDIT:

Since the OP, I have done the following:

$3x + 5y = n$

$3x +5y + 1= n+1$

$3x+5y + 6-5 = n+1$

$3x +5y + 2*3 - 5 = n+1$

$3(x + 2) + 5(y-1) = n+1$

Therefore, if $y \ne 0$, then $x+2$ 3-capacity boxes and $y-1$ 5-capacity boxes can be used to fulfil an order of size $n+1$.

Comment: How about considering as the base case that the company can ship $9$, $10$ and $11$ bananas? Then prove that for $n\geq 9$, if the company can ship $P(n)$, $P(n+1)$, and $P(n+2)$ bananas, then it can also ship $P(n+3)$, $P(n+4)$, and $P(n+5)$ bananas.

Comment: By the way, the Frobenius problem is related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem It says that you can ship any number of bananas of at least $5\cdot 3 - 5 - 3 + 1 = 8$ in number.

Comment: Why do we need to also prove $P(n+2)$ for this particular problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re supposed to assume that the cases are always shipped completely filled. Thus, there’s no way for the company to satisfy an order for $1,2,4$, or $7$ bananas. It *can* fill an order for $8$, by shipping a $3$ and a $5$, or an order for $9$, by shipping three $3$s.

HINT: Suppose that it can fill an order for $n$ bananas; i.e., there are non-negative integers $k$ and $\ell$ such that $3k+5\ell=n$.

- Can it fill an order for $n+3$ bananas?
- Wev’e seen that it can fill orders for $8$ or $9$ bananas. Can it fill an order for $10$?

If you answer those two questions correctly, you have the necessary pieces for a proof by induction. It doesn’t go from $n$ to $n+1$; it goes from $n$ to ... ? And it has more than one base case.

Further help, spoiler-protected:

> Once you’ve verified that they can send $8,9$, or $10$ bananas, you can keep adding boxes of $3$ to get any larger number. If you want to be more formal about it, you can show by three inductions on $n$ that they can send $3n+2$ for any $n\ge 2$, $3n$ for any $n\ge 3$, and $3n+1$ for any $n\ge 3$. Since every integer can be written in one of these three forms, ...

Comment: I have added an edit into the OP, is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: @cp101020304: No, because $y-1$ may be negative. Don’t try to go in steps of $1$. Use $k$ starting points and go in steps of $k$ for some $k>1$; my answer points you towards the right $k$.

Comment: Okay, so is there a particular reason why the first question is if it can fulfil an order for $n+3$ bananas?

Comment: @cp101020304: Yes, there is, but I’d rather not give it outright, at least not yet, because it very nearly completes the proof. Can you answer that question?

Comment: $3x + 5y + 3 = n+3$.

$3(x+1) + 5y = n+3$.

Something like that? It is quite intuitive that if we have some arbitrary n (e.g $9$), then $n+3$ can be fulfilled by having $4$ 3-capacity boxes.

Comment: @cp101020304: Yes: if there are integers $x,y\ge 0$ such that $3x+5y=n$, then clearly $3(x+1)+5y=n+3$, so if they can fill an order for $n$ bananas, they can fill one for $n+3$. Since they can fill one for $9$, it follows by induction that that they can fill one for $3k$ for any $k\ge 3$. That gives us $9,12,15,\ldots$; how do we get the rest?

Comment: do the same thing for $n+2$ and $n+1$?

Comment: @cp101020304: That won’t work, because you can’t send a box of $2$ bananas or $1$ banana. Try thinking more in words and less in algebraic computation. The reason that we can go from $n$ to $n+3$ is that if we can somehow ship $n$ bananas, we can always send one more box of $3$ to make a total of $n+3$. The base case of $9$ gives us $9,12,15,\ldots$ as we keep adding another box of $3$. What if we start at $8$ and keep adding boxes of $3$?

Comment: How can we start at $8$ if $n \ge 9$? We can start at 9 and send another box of $5$ to make a total of $n+5$, which will give us $9,14,19,...$

Comment: @cp101020304: You can prove the stronger result that the company can actually fulfil any order for at least $8$ bananas; that certainly implies the desired result. Don’t bother adding boxes of $5$: apart from the ones that you use to send $8$ or $10$ bananas, you don’t need them, and *not* using them makes the proof shorter.

Comment: Sure, so adding boxes of $3$ starting from $8$ will give us $8,11,14,17,...$. How does that prove that the company can fulfil any order $n \ge 8$?

Comment: @cp101020304: It doesn’t, because you’re not done yet. But look: you’ve now taken care of $8,9,11,12,14,15,17,18,20,21,\ldots$, so you’re missing $10,13,16,19,\ldots$. At this point you should be able to find a way to deal with them.

Comment: I see! Thank you for bearing with me hahaha

Comment: @cp101020304: You’re welcome.